# Zenity - different returned values

Tags: list, zenity

On "Linux Mint 16 Petra" i type this command :

```
zenity --list --column "test" a b c
```

I select the item 'a', then the returnning value is randomly

```
a or a|a
```

How do you explain this ? is it a zenity bug ?
How to get only 'a' ?

Regards.

Comment: Just found that : select a + keyboard enter returns a|a. Select a + valid button returns a. So how to get 'a' on both cases ?

Answer (score 2):

It is a pretty annoying bug. Not the first one this year too.

open=$(find "${@}" -iname "*$string*" | zenity --list --title "Search results" --text "Please select file or directory to open:" --width 800 --height 600 --column "Files")

## work-around:

opens=$(echo $open | cut -d "|" -f2)

Answer (score 0):

When you select "a" with mouse double click (or with the enter key on keyboard), the value is "a|a". When you select it and press "Ok", the value is "a".
I don't know exactly why.

A simple workaround could be :

```
TMP=$(zenity --list --column "test" a b c) # Save the returned value in TMP
VAL=${TMP:0:1} # Keep the first character of TMP and put it in VAL
echo $VAL # VAL = "a", "b" or "c"
```

Comment: So if values are more than one char, we have to split : `TMP=$(zenity --list --column "test" item1 another andthelast); # Save the returned value in TMP`
`IFS='|' read -a array <<< "$TMP"; # split on | if exists`
`VAL="${array[0]}";`
`echo $VAL;`

Comment: Yes, it's a simple solution to keep the right result. But I really don't know why Zenity returns different results...

Answer (score 0):

Print *every* value in a `|` separated list : `zenity --list --print-column=ALL` (...) and get the whole selected row.